# Why this factory does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to unit test my app.I have a `order` model and this model has a attr_accessor `register_client`.If accessor has a value `1`:

```
order.client = User.create
```

it works, but when I trying to test this - I create a factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :order do
    username Faker::Name.name
    register_client "1"
  end

end
```

and it fails with:

```
order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
order.client
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    #put necessary here
  end

  factory :order do

    trait :with_client do
      register_client "1"
      association :client, factory: :user
    end

    trait :unregistered_client do 
      username { Faker::Name.name }
    end

    factory :order_with_client,  traits: [:with_client]
  end

end
```

Then you'd have:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:order, :with_client)
# same as
FactoryGirl.create(:order_with_client)

FactoryGirl.create(:order, :unregistered_client)
```

Comment: then you have it since you have the client relationship

Comment: the client can be registered or not.for this I using the accessor `register_client`, its value can be '0' (client do not wan register) and '1' (client want register)